# Install Python on Centos

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, python

I have some scripts on my server that I to run when the url is loaded so I have been looking around and I'm not sure but from what I can tell I want to install apache python? Because right now I have a script in the /var/www/html/ and when I go there I just see the python script in plain text, I want it to run when I go there. Someone told me to "configure apache to know you want to run the python scripts", but Im not totally sure what that means?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so Apache and Python are two very different things that can work together to host a web application.

Apache is a web server, you make requests to it by browsing to that devices URI and the Apache web server does its thing and serves up a response based on the request it was sent. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server

Python is a scripting language. It allows a computer to run a dynamic script at the time it is called and when used in conjunction with Apache, allows you to create a dynamic website, like Facebook for want of better example. A client makes a request to your Apache server, the server looks in the correct folder and finds your script and Python executes it and hands the result to Apache which serves that as a response back to the client.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

You need to do a fair bit of reading before venturing too far into this, it helps immensely if you have a fair understanding of how these higher level things work before trying to configure the more advanced side of things.

Here's a guide on setting up Apache to work with `mod_python`:
https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-2-web-server-on-centos-6

**EDIT**
I think it might make life a hell of a lot easier if you used a web control panel to deal with the more complex side of things if it's a website you're trying to set up. This way you wouldn't have to deal with things like DNS and routing. The CPanel would handle the harder stuff for you. 
An added bonus of some is that by default they support web server setups with python installed, see http://ajenti.org/

I've actually used Ajenti-V and quite liked it and can vouch for the fact that it indeed supports Python out of the box.

[Install Ajenti-V On RHEL Machines](http://support.ajenti.org/topic/423530-installing-ajenti-v-on-centosrhel/)

Good luck!